numbering on jaws of a lathe chuck
Jaws for a Nova lathe chuck are numbered 1 through 4.  Why is that?  Is it important to always put them in that order?  Is it important to put #1 where the previous #1 was etc.?  If it is important to always keep jaw #1 in a specific place, why isn't the base also numbered 1 through 4?
It would be nice if it was only necessary to put them in order going around and not have to worry about always getting #1 where the previous #1 was.

For what reason would someone downvote this question?

Perhaps the classic reason for downvoting on StackExchange is lack of apparent research (this is a requirement of the SE model as you know). If you're on a computer hover the pointer over the downvote arrow and you'll see this reason leads in the popup, "This question does not show any research effort".



In the first image, taken only a couple hours ago, you can see that the jaws of this three jaw chuck meet in a proper manner. During that time, I then re-located the jaws to be effectively one slot clockwise.
The result was that the jaws met in a proper manner.
More recently, I realized that I needed to perform the move in a less controlled manner and simply swapped two of them to break the continuous marking aspect. This is the second image.
I do not have a non-independent 4 jaw chuck on which to experiment, and an independent 4 jaw chuck won't care which jaw is in which slot, as each is adjusted for the work piece.
You may discover that you can rotate the slots versus jaw number in a controlled manner and find no problems, but I suspect that if you break the sequence, you'll get an irregular grip.
For a non-independent jaw chuck, it's important to apply pressure to all four jaws simultaneously as you insert them. An extra set of hands or a vegetable-style rubber band over the jaws can be used to accomplish this. As you have the jaws in the slots, rotate the key to "remove" them and observe (or feel) each one drop into the groove in turn. If one missed the correct sequence, when you tighten them, one or more will be out of grip.

@fred_dot_uThe Nova chuck for woodworking looks very different from the metal work jaws shown.  Nova chuck jaws are held in place by two screws each.  While the screws are loose the chuck is tightened so that the four jaws meet then the jaw screws are tightened the final 1/2 turn with an allen wrench.  Please confirm, you are saying so long as I keep the order 1,2,3,4 it does not matter where I start.

From the images on the Nova web site, it appears that the general construction of the chuck is similar and the add-on plates for wood working make it suitable for that type of turning. I suspect that the spiral within the chuck works the same way and one should still back off the jaws until each one clicks in turn, then return to tighten them. It means that the order is important, but initial placement will not be critical.
